# PHP, WordPress: Loop information from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I have four arrays that I get from the database unserialize inside a loop, and than get a single value from a loop inside this loop :) Code below:

```
<?php

// MONTH
$eduGraduationDateMonth = get_post_custom_values('rbeduendmonth');
// YEAR
$eduGraduationDateYear = get_post_custom_values('rbeduendyear');
// PLACE
$eduPlace = get_post_custom_values('rbeduplace');
// FACULTY
$eduFaculty = get_post_custom_values('rbedusubject');

foreach($eduGraduationDateMonth as $eduMonthValue){
  $eduMonthUnser = unserialize($eduMonthValue);
  foreach($eduMonthUnser as $eduMonthUnserValue){
    echo $eduMonthUnserValue;
  }
}

foreach($eduGraduationDateYear as $eduYearValue){
  $eduYearUnser = unserialize($eduYearValue);
  foreach($eduYearUnser as $eduYearUnserValue){
    echo $eduYearUnserValue;
  }
}

foreach($eduPlace as $eduPlaceValue){
  $eduPlaceUnser = unserialize($eduPlaceValue);
  foreach($eduPlaceUnser as $eduPlaceUnserValue){
    echo $eduPlaceUnserValue;
  }
}

foreach($eduFaculty as $eduFacultyValue){
  $eduFacultyUnser = unserialize($eduFacultyValue);
  foreach($eduFacultyUnser as $eduFacultyUnserValue){
    echo $eduFacultyUnserValue;
  }
}

?>
```

Of course when i echo it i get something like: **mayseptember19901996College NameAnother CollegeITWriter**

What I need is to loop it somehow so i can get the following:

**May 1990**

**College Name**

**IT**

---

**September 1996**

**Another College**

**Writer**

How could I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: If you will use key,value pair you can easily achieve what you want.that to in a single loop.

Comment: so should i do something like `foreach($eduGraduationDateMonth as $key => $eduMonthValue)`. Or where exactly should i add a `$key` thing?

Comment: For all your four variables form array using key,value and make sure that you assign same key to all four variables i.e. 0,1,2.... for simplification then write one foreach in which try like this foreach($eduGraduationDateMonth as $key=>$eduMonthValue){ echo $eduMonthValue." ".$eduGraduationDateYear[$key]."<br>";echo $eduPlace[$key]." <br>";echo $eduFaculty[$key]."<br>;}

Comment: I got a little bit confused on that :) Could you show some simple example, please, so I could understand how form an array for these variables and assign key and value?

Comment: while using this get_post_custom_values() make sure that you are getting array with same set of keys for all four variables.

Comment: Good i think some has answered below same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the order and ad some html elements ..everything is done .updated

```
   <?php

// MONTH
$eduGraduationDateMonth = get_post_custom_values('rbeduendmonth');
// YEAR
$eduGraduationDateYear = get_post_custom_values('rbeduendyear');
// PLACE
$eduPlace = get_post_custom_values('rbeduplace');
// FACULTY
$eduFaculty = get_post_custom_values('rbedusubject');

foreach($eduGraduationDateMonth as $eduMonthValue){
  $eduMonthUnser = unserialize($eduMonthValue);

}

foreach($eduGraduationDateYear as $eduYearValue){
  $eduYearUnser = unserialize($eduYearValue);

}

foreach($eduPlace as $eduPlaceValue){
  $eduPlaceUnser = unserialize($eduPlaceValue);

}

foreach($eduFaculty as $eduFacultyValue){
  $eduFacultyUnser = unserialize($eduFacultyValue);

}
foreach($eduMonthUnser as $key =>$value){
    echo $value.'<br>';
    echo $eduYearUnser[$key].'<br>'; 
    echo $eduPlaceUnser[$key].'<br>';
    echo $eduFacultyUnser[$key].'<br>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: nope, this will just add line breaks to it, and i need to be like information about 1 college, than information about second college and so on.

Comment: Ok, the edited one worked just perfect, thank you! :)

Comment: This will work but I don't prefer it. In the final loop, $key is based on $eduMonthUnser. What if that $key does not exist in year, place or faculty? If your form is properly coded then you should not have any problem. For robustness, better to check that $key exists.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked on wordpress but I took a quick look at the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

You can use `get_post_custom()` function and then loop over that. Within each iteration of the loop, access all the keys for that iteration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `get_post_custom()` doesn't work with arrays as i remember, it returns Array instead. There is a property called `get_post_custom_values()` to get arrays from data base.

Comment: I don't understand. The documentation says it will return "as a multidimensional array containing all custom fields of the current post." Try it out. Will be interested to know if it really doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, yeah my bad, `get_post_meta()` doesn't work with arrays. But `get_post_custom()` will return information from all the fields in the form, and this form has around 100 input fields, and user can dynamicaly add unlimited number of extra inputs, so it will be pretty hard to work with all that information if i use `get_post_custom()` :)